# Python tool to stress python web app

Tags: python, api, stress-testing

I need a python tool to stress a web application built in python. In summary, the application receives request as text or text files sent by customers and returns the results.
What I need is to simulate these requests simultaneously. Maybe 10, 20, 50 requests at the same time.
I've been reviewing the **FunkLoad** testing tool, but I'm not sure if it could serve for my purposes.
I've also taken a look at [PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy) but I'm a bit lost.
Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about Apache Benchmark? The utility can perform 10, 20, 50 concurrent requests, looks that exactly what you need.

Here is the example:

`ab -n 100 -c 10 "http://localhost:8080"`

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ApacheBench if you're interested.

Comment: Ok but.. I do not need to test the simultaneous connections that the web server supports. Is to simulate the use of the application from several customers at once.

Comment: Yep. Seems to me that are the same actions.